# Date picker style issue in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker

In my Xamarin Forms project, datepicker UI is breaking and it is showing on top of the splash screen background like below:

[image]

Code:

```
<DatePicker
x:Name="date_picker"
PropertyChanged="DateValue"
Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}"/>
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle" TargetType="DatePicker">
  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
  <Setter Property="Format" Value="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Start" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

I am facing this issue after updating the Xamarin form version to 5.0.0.2515.

Is this a known issue? Please suggest a solution.

**Update-20220824**

I tested the same feature on a new project. I have updated the Xamarin forms version to 5.0.0.2515 and added the date picker on that project. The date picker feature is working fine on the new project. The issue is only on our existing project. So is this happening because of any other package?

Comment: Can you provide some code? I can test on my side. thanks.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Updated the question with the required code.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: I tested the code on the old xamarin.form version 5.0.0.2196 and it worked well, then I tested on the new version 5.0.0.2515 and it worked well too. So the problem may not relate to the xamarin.form version.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I tested the datepicker feature on both old xamarin.form version 5.0.0.2196 and new xamarin.form version 5.0.0.2515, but getting the same issue.

Comment: Can I ask you for the minimum demo? I want to reproduce the problem which you discribed. Thanks.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I will provide a sample as soon as possible.